# Remove failed Kubernetes job pods when the same job succeeds

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

We are running Kubernetes cronjobs and monitor failed pods/jobs on a dashboard. When a job fails the dashboard turns red. We are using [history limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits) to keep five failed and one successful job. Everything works well... except that we need to act on the alarms manually and the dashboard is very visible.

Most jobs will simply do their thing the next time they run, so if job A has failed and then succeeds, the failure is irrelevant. We would like to get rid of failed pods for jobs that have failed, but then succeeded on a later run. In other words, keep five failures, but on the first success clear the failures and keep only the success.

Is this possible (ideally without writing a complex program that runs kubectl commands)?

Comment: Have you tried just creating a `CronJob` with a sufficient `Role`  to implement the logic you just described? No, kubernetes is not going to do that logic by itself, if that's what you're asking

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure I can solve it that way, but I'm still hoping for something built-in or by all means an open source package. I checked the documentation before asking, so I agree that it is probably not built in.